# Android Retrieving MAC Address

Tags: java, android

I would like to retreive MAC address if internet connection is enabled.
I used this code below but it works only with wifi :

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = info.getMacAddress());
```

I also try this one but i get error at getRuntime :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("adb", "shell", "getprop", "ril.wifi_macaddr")
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
String macAddress = br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo deviceWifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = deviceWifiInfo.getMacAddress();
```

and add permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: this code works but only with wifi enabled.What i want is to get mac address even when i'm using eth0 or data connection .